# Wrap element with div

Tags: jquery

**jquery-3.2.1.min.js**

I clone an element and would like the cloned element be wrapped in  tag.

```
function add_and_keeper(){
  let $and_keepers = $("#and_keepers"); // $and_keepers = [td#and_keepers]
  let $keeper_choice_clone = $person_choice.clone() // $keeper_choice_clone = [select#id_person_choice, prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]
  let $wrapped = $keeper_choice_clone.wrap("<div>"); // $wrapped = [select#id_person_choice, prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]
  let $new_elem = $and_keepers.append($wrapped).children("select:last-child");
}
```

Well, added is:

```
<select name="person_choice" id="id_person_choice">
  <option value="" selected="">---------</option>

  <option value="1">1: Smith </option>

  <option value="2">2: Johnson </option>

</select>
```

As we can see, it is not wrapped with div.

Desired is:

```
<div><select name="person_choice" id="id_person_choice">
  <option value="" selected="">---------</option>

  <option value="1">1: Smith </option>

  <option value="2">2: Johnson </option>

</select></div>
```

Could you help me understand where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always best to [read the documentation of the method you're using](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/): :-)

> This method returns the original set of elements for chaining purposes.

So when you then append it, you remove it from the wrapper and instead put it in its new parent.

Instead, since you're dealing with an element that isn't in the DOM, create the `div` and add to it with `append`:

```
function add_and_keeper(){
    let $and_keepers = $("#and_keepers"); // $and_keepers = [td#and_keepers]
    let $keeper_choice_clone = $person_choice.clone() // $keeper_choice_clone = [select#id_person_choice, prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]
    let $div = $("<div>");
    $div.append($keeper_choice_clone);
    let $new_elem = $and_keepers.append($div).children("select:last-child");
}
```

That can also be written more concisely if you like:

```
function add_and_keeper(){
    let $and_keepers = $("#and_keepers"); // $and_keepers = [td#and_keepers]
    let $keeper_choice_clone = $person_choice.clone() // $keeper_choice_clone = [select#id_person_choice, prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]
    let $new_elem = $and_keepers.append($("<div>").append($keeper_choice_clone)).children("select:last-child");
}
```

I tend to prefer the former for debugging.